# Use nmcli to modify VPN password?

Tags: ubuntu, networkmanager, vpn, nmcli

With `nmcli`, I can modify VPN data like this:

```
nmcli con modify myvpn vpn.data 'refuse-pap = yes, user = xxx'
```

So I'm wondering if I can set password this way as well?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, you can modify the value of any property with `nmcli`. In this case, you would use:

```
nmcli con modify "myvpn" vpn.secrets "password=myverysecretpassword"
```

Comment: Note that this will, of course, echo your password as you type it.

Comment: It will also store your password in your shell history.

Comment: and if you use gpaste and it stores history and you copied your password from something else like lastpass that buffer will have it too ;-)

Comment: This answer shows how to prevent echoing/saving the password: https://askubuntu.com/a/1179680/732215 -- (IFS='' read -s -r -p '802.1X password '; nmcli connection modify id example 802-1x.password "$REPLY")

Comment: That can still put the password in the process table though very very briefly!